# Can not get value inside function using PHP

Tags: php, file

I have one issue.I am trying to print the file data into one called function its not printing anything using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if($action=='addSellRent'){
   if(array_key_exists('file1',$_FILES)){
        $result[]=uploadSellImage($_FILES);
  }
}
function uploadSellImage($_FILES){
    print_r($_FILES);exit;
}
```

Here inside trying to print the file but its showing blank. Here I need to pass the file data to the `uploadSellImage` function and try to doing some operation there. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function uploadSellImage($upload){
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($upload);die;
}
```